# AZure AD connect and Azure AD firewall

Tags: azure

I was trying to provision users from On Premise AD to Azure AD using Azure AD connect agent. From my organization the firewall is blocking the provisioning.Can any one please let me know the Azure AD IP address to raise the firewall request.

Referred the following url - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-ports

Answer (score 0):

You will find the information from behind a link, from the url you posted:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/office-365-urls-and-ip-address-ranges-8548a211-3fe7-47cb-abb1-355ea5aa88a2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bkmk_identity_ip

As soon as you open up the list of IP ranges, you will realize that the list is quite huge and it can change over a course of time. Thats why I do suggest another approach instead of allowing outbound traffic to specific CIDR blocks or IP ranges.

Edit: this link leads directly to the expandable IP range list:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/office-365-urls-and-ip-address-ranges-8548a211-3fe7-47cb-abb1-355ea5aa88a2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bkmk_identity_ip

Comment: Thanks for the reply .So Should i need to open the firewall for the following URLs alone from my organization   *broadcast.officeapps.live.com,
*excel.officeapps.live.com,
*powerpoint.officeapps.live.com,
*view.officeapps.live.com
*visio.officeapps.live.com,
*word-edit.officeapps.live.com,
*word-view.officeapps.live.com,
office.live.com,

Comment: The URL's you mentioned are related to Office 365 applications. Maybe you looked at the wrong topic on the website? See the addresses and URL's under the "Authentication and identity FQDNs" topic, which is above the ones you just listed.

Comment: Hi, Still i am confused with this IP address.Can you please help me with the exact ip address. Please let me know the exact destination IPs of the Azure AD connect so  that i can raise a firewall request within my organization for the following ports 443 and 80. This would help me a lot to resolve this firewall issue

Comment: Ok i got your point Antti. So the destination IPs are listed under 
"Office 365 authentication and identity IPv4 endpoints routable through the Internet and ExpressRoute". Is it enough to raise the firewall for the mentioned ips?

Comment: Sorry, I was away from a computer for a couple of weeks. Yes, that should be enough in my opinion.